# Behavior of Varchar with spaces at the end

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

When I use a Varchar with spaces it ignores the spaces at the end.

ex:

```
declare @X varchar(50)
```

This...

```
set  @X= 'John'
```

...is the same as...

```
set @X= 'John           '
```

It considers these to be equal.  How can I cause the system to recognize these as different?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Everything is just according the ANSI standard:

[Trailing blanks explained](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316626):

> SQL Server follows the ANSI/ISO SQL-92 specification (Section 8.2,
>   , General rules #3) on how to compare strings
>   with spaces. The ANSI standard requires padding for the character
>   strings used in comparisons so that their lengths match before
>   comparing them. The padding directly affects the semantics of WHERE
>   and HAVING clause predicates and other Transact-SQL string
>   comparisons. For example, Transact-SQL considers the strings 'abc' and
>   'abc ' to be equivalent for most comparison operations.
>
> The only exception to this rule is the LIKE predicate. When the right
>   side of a LIKE predicate expression features a value with a trailing
>   space, SQL Server does not pad the two values to the same length
>   before the comparison occurs. Because the purpose of the LIKE
>   predicate, by definition, is to facilitate pattern searches rather
>   than simple string equality tests, this does not violate the section
>   of the ANSI SQL-92 specification mentioned earlier.

Here's a well known example of all the cases mentioned above:

```
DECLARE @a VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @b varchar(10)

SET @a = '1'
SET @b = '1 ' --with trailing blank

SELECT 1
WHERE 
    @a = @b 
AND @a NOT LIKE @b
AND @b LIKE @a
```

Here's some more detail about [trailing blanks and the `LIKE` clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx).

**BUT** if you want to differ them - you may decide to use `DATALENGTH` function instead of `LEN`, because

```
SELECT 1 WHERE LEN('John ') = LEN('John')
```

will put you 1 instead of

```
SELECT 1 WHERE DATALENGTH('John ') = DATALENGTH('John')
```

**The solution** is

- to use DATALENGTH function to differ between strings
- to cast the string into NVARCHAR type - may be better declare this type to parameter of SP

Comment: Spectacular post, finally found some good info

Answer (score -2):

You can simply add a white space to your condition.

```
set @X= 'John           \n'
```

[Trailing Spaces in String Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896273(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: `\n` has no significance in SQL Server. It is not interpreted as a new line. This is not an answer to the question asked anyway.

Comment: @MartinSmith but it is written in MSDN "If you have to have trailing spaces in your string, you should consider appending a white space character at the end, so that SQL Server does not trim the string."